# Adding direct link to post editor in admin menu

Tags: navigation, admin-menu

I'm trying to make a shortcut in navigation that will take user to one certain post. 
So far I'm using

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_position');

function add_custom_menu_position() {
add_menu_page('FeaturedJobs', 'Featured Jobs', 'edit_posts', 'edit.php?post=706&action=edit',18); 
}
```

The item does show up in the admin menu, but every time I try to use it, it inserts admin? as a part of the link and I get *You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.* error.

The final link looks like this: http://website_url/wp-admin/admin.php?page=post.php?post=706&action=edit

I know that I have enough capabilities to edit it, because I'm on an admin account and also once I use a regular edit link (http://website_url/wp-admin/post.php?post=706&action=edit), it works fine. I'm rather sure the problem is there because the link I'm trying to reach is wrong, but I can't find a way to link to it in any other way.

I'll be grateful for any hints,
E.

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding the menu slug as
`edit.php?post=706&action=edit`, it is adding in the url after `admin.php` considering it as a new page in admin dashboard (general behaviour of `add_menu_page()`)

So, you should give a fully qualified url instead. I think, `admin_url()` should help.

Try adding

`admin_url('post.php?post=706&action=edit')`

Or

`admin_url('edit.php?post=706&action=edit')`

instead of

`edit.php?post=706&action=edit`

as menu slug.

Comment: It sill says I don't have permissions to access the page. Also the output changed to http://website_url/wp-admin/admin.php?page=http:/website_url/wp-admin/edit.php?post=706&action=edit

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'register_custom_menu_link' );

function register_custom_menu_link(){
    add_menu_page('FeaturedJobs', 'Featured Jobs', 'edit_posts', 'featured_jobs', '__return_null', 'dashicons-external', 18);
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'redirect' );
function redirect() {
    if(!empty($_GET['page']) && $_GET['page'] == 'featured_jobs') {
        // Your post id
        $post_id = 706;
        wp_redirect(wp_specialchars_decode(get_edit_post_link($post_id)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue but was able to accomplish this with the help of wp_redirect and [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/246003/226863).

My solution ended up looking something like this:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_custom_menu_position');

function add_custom_menu_position() {
$hook = add_menu_page('FeaturedJobs', 'Featured Jobs', 'edit_posts', 'featured-jobs',18); 
add_action('load-' . $hook, function () {
            wp_redirect(admin_url('post.php?post=706&action=edit'));
        });
}
```